# DLL in the GAC Ignored after ResolveEventHandler Added

Tags: c#, gac

I was asked to debug a .NET Framework C# program *OurProgram*.  I am told that it worked in the past.  *OurProgram* uses methods from DLLs added to the global assembly cache (GAC) by another product's setup, e.g., *DllInGac.dll*.

At the beginning of execution, *OurProgram* calls `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(OurResolveEventHandler);`.  Later in execution, *OurProgram* can instantiate an object from class *OtherClass* in *DllInGac.dll*.  However, when *OurProgram* calls a method on the object, *OurResolveEventHandler* is called, and an exception occurs because *OurResolveEventHandler* does not return *DllInGac.dll*.

If I add code to instantiate an object from *OtherClass* before *OurProgram* calls `...AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(...` and if the code also calls a method on the object, then in code executing after `...AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(...`, instantiating *OtherClass* and calling one of its methods is successful, and *OurResolveEventHandler* is not called.

Based on e.g., [How the Runtime Locates Assemblies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/deployment/how-the-runtime-locates-assemblies), I did not think that ResolveEventHandler is supposed to make the GAC be ignored.  I would not think that the way to fix this problem is kludgily to instantiate an object from every needed DLL in the GAC and call a method on the object during *OurProgram*'s initialization.  I would be grateful to learn how to make adding a ResolveEventHandler not cause *DllInGac.dll* in the GAC to be ignored.

Comment: No, that's not how the GAC works.  Obvious reasons are targeting .NETCore (aka .NET 5 and up), having the wrong version in the GAC and forgetting to run the installer that puts it in the GAC.  Very first thing to do is look in source control to find out what changed recently.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that the GAC is not supposed to act as it does with _OurProgram_ and also for the suggestions.  _OurProgram_ and _DllInGac.dll_ both target .NET Framework 4.8.  I am pretty sure that _DllInGac_ is properly installed; it is working well elsewhere, including with another executable on the same computer where _OurProgram_ has the GAC problem.  I hope to try _OurProgram_ with an older version of _DllInGac_ from when _OurProgram_ was working properly if I can contact _OurProgram_'s creators.